# setting a row of a matrix to 0, in eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

kind of strange:

I'm trying to set a full row of a matrix to 0 and neither of the four obvious constructs in eigen would compile:

```
//U is a p by p matrix. I wanna set its last column to 0.0f
U=solved.eigenvectors();   

U.row(p-1).array()=0;              //don't compile
U.row(p-1).setZero(1,p);           //don't compile
U.row(p-1).array().setZero(p);     //don't compile
U.bottomRows(1).setZero(p);        //don't compile
```

I also tried other variations on these themes but neither passed the compiler

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use:

```
U.row(p-1).setZero();
```

Comment: One more question: how can I do this directly? --e.g. solved.eigenvectors().row(p-1).setZero();

Comment: @user189035 You cannot do this as [`eigenvectors()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html#a3236af3afbc89241aaed4fc868aa8435) returns a constant.